# How to educate folks on site policy sans contact?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues

This is related to [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users) and [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user). I understand we are not allowed to contact others, so I'm wondering how to educate others on site policy.

Here's the situation: Suggested Edits had a capitalization change in the title. The change in case was on a tag. The appropriate action would have been to remove the tag. A vote was cast to reject with a custom message "See [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)" (the message could not be more helpful or longer because of a size limit). However, others approved the change. So it appears the editor and three approvers could be made aware of the site's policy.

Here's the question in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4799856.

So the question is: how do we educate folks on site policy given we are not allowed to contact them?

Comment: I'm amazed that you were able to locate the relevant meta question *before* it was approved. Almost always, if I try to write a custom message the edit is approved before I can hit *Reject*.

Comment: Tangentially, I'd say the original title was arguably better than the "de-tagified" version you edited it to, since it was at least less ambiguous; see ["Please do not remove key words that happen to be tags when doing so makes the titles muddier"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179969). The real problem, though, is that *both* versions of the title are pretty awful, as is the phrasing of the question itself. It really needs more than just deleting a few words to turn it into a good question.

Comment: You know, those ratios are quite worrying for the accepters: 423/24, **971/84**, 244/20. I have 733/671, which is much more even. That should be much more of a flag.

Comment: @gunr2171: You're saying that half of all suggested edits are either bad, or should be regarded as bad?  That doesn't sound like a very cheerful statistic.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, who said stats have to be cheerful? I'm not saying that "you have to be even" with your approve/rejects, I'm saying that it's a bit odd to have 10-17 times the amount of approves than rejects with >200 approves.

Comment: @gunr2171: Kinda depends on what the actual good/bad suggested edits ratio is, doesn't it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, seems that the approve/reject ratio of the site is 4:1. [my query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/194033).

Comment: @gunr2171: That seems a bit more reasonable than 50:50.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't know that more than half are bad, but less than half are good.

Comment: @gunr2171 Those stats you queried are "all time" though right? A few *things* were different years ago. Fewer users meant fewer people with the rep to edit, fewer robo reviewers, etc. More users means more people suggesting edits, and statistics and scientific proof shows that more people makes everything worse. My approve/reject is 111/153 on SO, and 66/72 on MSE. I do see more "not so useful" edit suggestions than I do approve-able ones.