# For gosh sakes, please let me finish my edit reviews!

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

It never fails that every time I start doing [suggested edit reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) that there are 1-2 of the 7 or so reviews where something was really wrong and I was rejecting the edit, but before I could reject it, it was *already approved*! :(

Stack Overflow *really* needs to do something about this problem. It is totally insufficient to require a reviewer to go into a question or answer where an edit was approved and fix it.

To give an example, this is how I feel when this happens:

> **You:** "Hey, Gary. I really need your advice. Is cutting my foot off for no reason a good idea?"
>
> **Me:** "Absolutely not!"
>
> **You:** "Too slow! :) Already cut it off. If you want to sew it back on for me, here's a needle and some thread."
>
> **Me:** "WTF?!"

Why not lock the edit for review for either the duration that it is open, or, at the very least, lock the review for some amount of time (30, 60, 120, 240 seconds or whatever works best) as soon as someone starts reviewing, and then, after that time, give an indication on the page that the review is now unlocked and someone else can edit it?

I understand that Stack Exchange is working at large scale and a lot of interaction with the server even in reviews can be a big deal, but something needs to be done to solve this, because it is severely affecting the quality of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I feel your pain, but if you are going to use the "feature-request" tag, suggest something that we could do, or change to discussion and ask what we should do (also giving a suggestion).

Comment: Another thing we could do is [go after the people with high approve/reject ratios](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254678/how-to-educate-folks-on-site-policy-sans-contact#comment20406_254678). Almost all the time when this situation comes up, it's because of people with stats like this.

Comment: Also, that exclusive review period answer mentions that a [new feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158418/careless-review-upvotes-are-actively-contributing-to-the-quality-problem-not-co/159514#159514) was introduced to help with this, but either it was removed or is not working? @gunr2171 I like the idea to go after those people as a short-term solution and then to use exclusive review period as a long-term solution.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits

Comment: Locking the review wouldn't have meant that these bad edits wouldn't be approved, it would just mean that you wouldn't *know* that bad edits were being approved, and so you wouldn't be there to fix the problem.  (The one point where your analogy fails is that fixing the problem is as simple as rolling back the edit, which is a fair bit easier than sewing on an amputated foot.)

Comment: @Servy Here's an example: I see that someone has responded inline in a question or answer vs. comment or answer. I attempt to reject the edit, but it says that it was already approved and that I must edit the question or answer. That last part is "sewing on the foot". Rolling back the edit is not simple enough. It should either roll it back automatically because I rejected it, or it should provide a single click option there in the message to roll it back. The most insulting part of it: it rejects my valid edit because I was not fast enough.

Comment: @GaryS.Weaver It takes you three clicks to roll back an edit.  That's not *that* bad.  There are *far* more important changes that I'd like to see in the suggested edit review than the ability to roll back edits from any completed review page.

Comment: @Servy Three clicks to undo something that two robo reviewers incorrectly accepted? Why should I need to do that? I've already gone through clicks to start the review process, have spent time reviewing the edit, and clicked as many times as required to reject the edit. But, even worse is that the time I spent to try to help S.O. was wasted before those three clicks. I think a single click is in order. They can prioritize this below other changes if need be, but it is a valid feature request.

Comment: @GaryS.Weaver There are plenty of actual problems when reviewing suggested edits.  You've even brought up several of them.  Requiring three clicks instead of one to roll back an improperly suggested edit simply isn't one of them.  It's not a sufficiently common case, it's not saving much of any effort, it's not actually *fixing* any problems, and there are plenty of far more valuable thing the developers can spend their time on.

Comment: "It's not a sufficiently common case"- untrue. That is the whole point of me bringing this up. It happens to me often. It does help fix it because it gives me a way to say "BS" when a question or answer is defaced without throwing up my hands because it is more work to undo the defacement. Why are you so against this? How would you suggest fixing the problem as defined?

Comment: I think the **286** upvotes on the robo-reviewers post indicate it's a pretty popular problem.

Comment: @GaryS.Weaver Effort should be spent actually preventing inappropriate edits from being approved, not allowing people to roll back the edits with 1 click instead of 3.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Those are people who want to fix the problem of inappropriate edits being approved.  Not people who want an added link for rolling back edits from within the review queue, or even people who want reviews to be locked while under review.  While this question does bring up a few problems that have been widely recognized as serious problems by many people for a long time, his proposed solutions to those problems are neither original, nor among the more popular.

Comment: @Servy the feature request described above (not in the comments, but the one being discussed) is to find a way to keep people from having their review invalidated before they finish. You and I got off on a tangent talking about what to do if that problem could not be resolved, which is related to having a single click vs. multiple to rollback a bad edit that was approved. That is a separate request, and I've not created it, because I'd rather see the initial problem fixed which is that valid reviews are getting ignored because they aren't fast enough, which in turn causes a morale problem.

Comment: @GaryS.Weaver Which makes it a duplicate of the 100 other "fix the review" questions all over meta, but yes, it is a problem, yes, something should be done, and no, these ideas are not original.

Comment: @Servy I agree. Did you see above where I commented and said this was a duplicate? I did not know it was a dupe when I first created it, or I would have just voted on the other related questions, which I ended up doing anyway. I'll also flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Servy Hmm apparently I can't close as duplicate of a question on another site. Which question on meta is it a dupe of, and will close it?