# Suggested Edit Reviews

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I am trying to help the community by editing posts and reviewing suggested edits on StackOverflow. Today I have encountered an edit but forgot to copy the link for it. I tried to reject the edit because it was invalid, but system told me it was already approved. I will explain the post since I don't have the link:

**Question:**

It was a long `SQL query` question, and the user was asking why am I getting the error with this query.

**Edited** by a User:

The editor corrected the wrong syntaxes and spelling mistakes in the query, and the comment for the edit was something like: this code won't work, corrected the code.

I know there are some topics about suggested edits but I couldn't find something like this.

What should I do in an event like this? Am I missing something? Shouldn't this be an `answer` instead of an `edit`? If you share my opinion, how did it become approved and what action should be taken in those "approved but invalid" edits?

Comment: Like you say, it's a definite reject. If someone asks a question you don't edit the fix into the question, you post an answer. You should roll back the edit.

Comment: You usually shouldn't be changing the code in a question, errors in it should be mentioned in a comment or even an answer if that's the actual problem. Whatever else that was edited outside the code should be left untouched.

Comment: possible duplicate of [For gosh sakes, please let me finish my edit reviews!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254830/for-gosh-sakes-please-let-me-finish-my-edit-reviews)

Answer (score 4):

Questions should not have the answer edited into the question, or worse still have the code in the question edited to fix the problems causing the question to be asked.

Reject such edits as "invalid edit".  If they get approved anyway, or you find an post edited in this manor outside of the review system, roll the edit back.

Comment: I don't think the OP is much confused about whether the edit was valid or not. The question seems to be: IF you're reviewing such an edit, and you're not a robo-approver, and while you're thinking and editing a bunch of badge-monkeys show up and approve it, what should we do? It's a bad edit, but we can't Reject the edit any more.

Comment: @AndrewS You can roll it back, as I *specifically* said in my answer.

Comment: Will that rollback be taken into account when evaluating the approvers moderating history?

Comment: @Deduplicator No, but it's the best that you can really do in the situation.  If you notice a pattern of bad behavior you can possibly flag for moderator attention, but by and large once it's approved its too late for you as a user to really do much of anything besides, as mentioned, fixing the actual post.