# Tell users that they can no longer review the edit as soon as they select a review option if the edit is no longer reviewable

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, user-interface

I was reviewing a suggested edit (the specific edit is irrelevant to the question), and selected <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd>. After doing so, I was surprised to see the suggested edit in the editor, instead of the previous revision.

Thinking that I had fat-fingered <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd>, I cancelled the edit, and selected <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd> again. I was bewildered to see, yet again, the suggested edit in the editor.

Thinking that there must have been a glitch, I decided to choose <kbd>Reject</kbd> instead. I did this, then I was shown the reject reason selection dialog. I selected an applicable rejection reason, and clicked <kbd>Reject</kbd>

I was then shown the following dialog:

> This edit was already approved - please visit the post and correct the edit.

Then it all made sense to me, it was loading the most recent revision of the post into the editor.

Allowing users to go through all of the motions of reviewing, then telling them at the last step that it was all for nothing, seems like you're purposefully wasting my time.

Hence, my feature request:

**Tell users that they can no longer review the edit as soon as they select a review option if the edit is no longer reviewable**

---

This is along the same lines as [For gosh sakes, please let me finish my edit reviews!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254830/4639281), but that is all about what happens when the edit is approved or rejected *after* selecting either <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd> or <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd>

This question is about what happens when an edit is approved or rejected *before* selecting either <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd> or <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd>

Comment: I would honestly love to read whatever anyone has to say about why this should stay the way it is. If users downvoting this feature request would be so kind as to comment on why they believe it should not be changed, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: -1, the review queues are already FUBAR, so there's little point in making incremental improvements (partially tongue-in-cheek)

Comment: @CodyGray That is a reasonable argument regardless of it's degree of being tongue-in-cheek. Though I would argue that any improvement to keep people interested in reviewing is a good thing.

Comment: Wasn't the ticket master supposed to reserve you enough time to review the edit before anyone else could review it?