# Mass roll back edits of user adding ios and xcode tag to all swift tags

Tags: support, tags, bulk-tagging

[Some specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2932036/daxesh-nagar) has been mass tagging [swift] questions with the [ios] and [xcode] tag and been getting through the review process as well. I have rolled back a couple, but I was wondering, is there any way one can tell him and the reviewers these edits are incorrect and a way to inform moderators of this so that these edits can be mass rolled back rather than one by one by hand.

Comment: I'm personally okay with the iOS tag being added. Not so much with Xcode unless its an IDE question.

Comment: @SantaClaus: You realize swift is mac **and** iOS, not iOS only? That's like adding windows to each [VB.net] question.

Comment: Well if it is an iOS question, then its okay. Sorry forgot about OSX.

Comment: The same user did the same to a bunch of Obj-C questions back around June 1.

Comment: This would sure be handy right about now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/moderators-should-be-able-to-manually-ban-users-from-suggesting-edits

Comment: I particularly love this: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5100863 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5100976 . Tempted to hand out review bans like candy.

Comment: Yup, lots of reviews approved by robo-reviewers with ~20:1 approve/reject ratios, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5100836) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5101199).

Comment: Every stupid suggested edit cloud has a silver lining of bannable reviewers...

Comment: Glad I always _skip_ suggested edit reviews in fields I have zero knowledge...

Comment: Also see [How to educate folks on site policy sans contact?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254678/how-to-educate-folks-on-site-policy-sans-contact).

Comment: @BradLarson: I should think that submitting the exact same edit suggestion after it's been rejected, with the exact same description, and not using comments to first discuss the edit.... has crossed into intentional vandalism and is suspension-worthy?

Comment: @DavidMulder: Don't be a robo-roller, either.  It appears some of the questions maybe should carry [tag:xcode], like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24017316/103167).

Comment: @BenVoigt: Still the rollback didn't make the question worse than after the edit. The iphone tag was definitely off topic, so rolling it back was I believe appropriate. Editing in the xcode tag would have been a valid contribution, but me not doing that was just as 'wrong' as you not doing that. (As in, fixing the wrong edit that should not have passed review did not create new responsibilities for me to edit in the xcode tag, although I probably would have if I had known more about pragma marks (just knew enough to know for sure iphone was wrong))

Comment: He's at it again today: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5278790 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5278839

Answer (score 16):

> is there anything one can tell him and the reviewer these edits are incorrect

Sure, just comment on any of the posts that (s)he edited and @reply him/her. Editors are valid targets of @replies, even though they are not suggested by the autocompletion feature.

> is there [...] a way to inform moderators of this

Sure, a flag.  Although they don't have any mass rollback tools.

Comment: But the comment, nor the flag would have anything to do with the post... they have to do with the user, adding them to the post, is that really the correct way? :S

Comment: @DavidMulder They absolutely have to do with the post.  They have to do with an inappropriate edit to the post.  How is that not relevant to the post?

Comment: Yes, flagging the improperly-edited post and putting in a custom message to the moderators explaining the situation is the correct thing to do.

Comment: @Servy: The post itself is valid, especially so after the rollback. The flag part I can still understand, but writing a comment about an invisible comment just feels really wrong.

Comment: @DavidMulder If you don't want to then don't.  You're not *obligated* to comment.  You asked if there was a way, there is, and it's an entirely appropriate use of comments.  If it simply bothers you, that's your decision to make.

Comment: @Servy: I am just expressing doubt regarding it being appropriate in the first place. And seeing my first comment being upvoted I am not alone in that feeling.

Comment: @DavidMulder Like I said, if it bothers you then that's your choice to not use it.  This is the appropriate tool for the job; it's also the only tool for the job.

Comment: @DavidMulder I use it regularly when I see useless edits. In 9 out of 10 cases it has the desired effect: the edits stop.